# How do I determine the CAML equivalent for a SQL query?

Tags: caml-query

I want to write an equivalent CAML query for the given SQL Query below:

```
select top 10 * from TestTable where ItemID in ( select top 10 ItemID from TestTable order by Views desc) order by UserName desc;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out U2U CAML Query Builder, it'll help you build any number of CAML Query possibilities that you need.

http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

Comment: But I do not see any option to get the top 10 items...

Comment: You need to use the RowLimit tag.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to make such a CAML query, any help

Comment: Just bang a <RowLimit>10<RowLimit> in your query somewhere inside <View></View>

Comment: i agree, rowcount works perfectly however it does not to make a sub query ...

Comment: You can do what you want to do without a subquery (which you can't do in CAML, and your sample is malformed SQL anyway).

Comment: but  still I do not know how to achieve that...